# PDEs on torus $\mathbb T$

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes

(Hope this question is o.k. for MO)

I have been learning   PDE(non linear dispersive equations) techniques, mainly using harmonic analysis(kind of Strichartz estimates, estimates for unimodular Fourier multiplier); to solve it.

But mainly with  underlying framework function spaces, which I have seen so far, are functions/distributions on $\mathbb R^{n}.$ (For instance,Sobolev spaces $H^{s}(\mathbb R^{n})$, Besove spaces $B^{p,q}(\mathbb R^{n})$, Modulation spaces $M^{p,q}(\mathbb R^{n})$, etc..)

> **My Question is**: Bit vague:How the theory had gone(or have been going), if one consider the underlying framework function spaces on torus $\mathbb T$ (for instance $H^{s}(\mathbb T)$, $A(\mathbb T)$, etc...) ? Is there something common in handling the non linear dispersive equations on compact group $\mathbb T$ and on group $\mathbb R$ ?
>
> What are the reference (book/ recent monograph/ fundamental papers) for the study of non linear dispersive equations on torus $\mathbb T$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit old, but I would check [Bourgain](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s8447.pdf) first.

A more recent reference is (among many others) the preprint of [Strunk](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/sfb701/files/preprints/sfb14006.pdf).